# Displaying the character on DIP203-6 LCD screen using beaglebone Black SPI

Tags: c, beagleboneblack, spi, lcd

I am trying to write a character to my DIP203-6 LCD using the beagle bone black SPI. I have Initialised the LCD screen as the cursor blinks at the right position. The problem I am facing is in writing the character as in [the data sheet](https://www.lcd-module.de/fileadmin/eng/pdf/doma/dip203-6e.pdf) the writing of character takes 10 bits but spi can take only 8 bits. The RS of the LCD needs to be made 1 according to the commands in the datasheet. I tend to get some garbage values.

In the int main() part, at the end you could see i am transferring the command using transfer function above the main

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/spi/spidev.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))
static void transfer(int fd, uint16_t* tx, uint8_t cs);
void init_display(int fd);

static void pabort(const char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    abort();
}

static const char *device = "/dev/spidev2.1";
static uint8_t mode=3;
static uint8_t bits = 8;
static uint32_t speed = 40000;
static uint16_t delay;

  //initialization of display

void init_display(int fd)
{
        int ret;
        uint16_t tx[] = {
                0x0F8, 0x000, 0x0C0,
                0x0F8, 0x060, 0x000,
                0x0F8, 0x060, 0x0C0,
                0x0FC, 0x090, 0x000,
                0x0FC, 0x000, 0x020,
                0x0FE, 0x000, 0x000,
                0x0F8, 0x000, 0x0C0,
                0x0F8, 0x0F0, 0x000,
                0x0F8, 0x080, 0x000,

        };

        for (ret=0; ret<27; ret++)
        {
                transfer(fd,&tx[ret], 0);
                  usleep(2000);
        }
}
static void transfer(int fd, uint16_t* tx, uint8_t cs){
    int ret;
    uint16_t rx[ARRAY_SIZE(tx)] = {0, };
    struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
        .tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx,
        .rx_buf = 0,
        .len = 1,
        .delay_usecs = delay,
        .speed_hz = speed,
        .bits_per_word = bits,
        .cs_change=cs,
    };
    printf("%u", cs);

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr);
    if (ret < 1)
        pabort("can't send spi message");

//  for (ret = 0; ret < ARRAY_SIZE(tx); ret++) {
    //  if (!(ret % 6))
        puts("");
    //  printf("%.2X ", rx[ret]);
    }
//  puts("");


static void print_usage(const char *prog)
{
    printf("Usage: %s [-DsbdlHOLC3]\n", prog);
    puts("  -D --device   device to use (default /dev/spidev1.1)\n"
         "  -s --speed    max speed (Hz)\n"
         "  -d --delay    delay (usec)\n"
         "  -b --bpw      bits per word \n"
         "  -l --loop     loopback\n"
         "  -H --cpha     clock phase\n"
         "  -O --cpol     clock polarity\n"
         "  -L --lsb      least significant bit first\n"
         "  -C --cs-high  chip select active high\n"
         "  -3 --3wire    SI/SO signals shared\n");
    exit(1);
}

static void parse_opts(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while (1) {
        static const struct option lopts[] = {
            { "device",  1, 0, 'D' },
            { "speed",   1, 0, 's' },
            { "delay",   1, 0, 'd' },
            { "bpw",     1, 0, 'b' },
            { "loop",    0, 0, 'l' },
            { "cpha",    0, 0, 'H' },
            { "cpol",    0, 0, 'O' },
            { "lsb",     0, 0, 'L' },
            { "cs-high", 0, 0, 'C' },
            { "3wire",   0, 0, '3' },
            { "no-cs",   0, 0, 'N' },
            { "ready",   0, 0, 'R' },
            { NULL, 0, 0, 0 },
        };
        int c;

        c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "D:s:d:b:lHOLC3NR", lopts, 
NULL);

        if (c == -1)
            break;

        switch (c) {
        case 'D':
            device = optarg;
            break;
        case 's':
            speed = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'd':
            delay = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'b':
            bits = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'l':
            mode |= SPI_LOOP;
            break;
        case 'H':
            mode |= SPI_CPHA;
            break;
        case 'O':
            mode |= SPI_CPOL;
            break;
        case 'L':
            mode |= SPI_LSB_FIRST;
            break;
        case 'C':
            mode |= SPI_CS_HIGH;
            break;
        case '3':
            mode |= SPI_3WIRE;
            break;
        case 'N':
            mode |= SPI_NO_CS;
            break;
        case 'R':
            mode |= SPI_READY;
            break;
        default:
            print_usage(argv[0]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret = 0;
    int fd;

    parse_opts(argc, argv);

    fd = open(device, O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0)
        pabort("can't open device");

    /*
     * spi mode
     */
    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MODE, &mode);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't set spi mode");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MODE, &mode);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't get spi mode");

    /*
     * bits per word
     */
    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't set bits per word");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't get bits per word");

    /*
     * max speed hz
     */
    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't set max speed hz");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't get max speed hz");

    printf("spi mode: %d\n", mode);
    printf("bits per word: %d\n", bits);
    printf("max speed: %d Hz (%d KHz)\n", speed, speed/1000);

    init_display(fd);
       usleep(20000);
    uint16_t hl[]={0X38,0X0E,0X06,0XF8,0X30,0x50,0x02};
    trnsfer(fd,hl,0);

    close(fd);

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LCD module uses SSD1803 controller. According to [the data sheet](https://www.lcd-module.de/fileadmin/eng/pdf/zubehoer/ssd1803_2_0.pdf), you need to transfer 3 bytes for write operation.

The first byte is a start byte composed of 5 bits of “1” followed by R/W, RS and end bit (“0”).

Next 2 bytes are data bytes. Lower 4 bits of data followed by four “0”s. Then, upper 4 bits of data followed by four “0”s.

- 1st byte: “1” “1” “1” “1” “1” R/W("0") RS("1") “0”
- 2nd byte: D0 D1 D2 D3 “0” “0” “0” “0”
- 3rd byte: D4 D5 D6 D7 “0” “0” “0” “0”

The figure 7-11 in the data sheet illustrates this operation.

[image]

Also, looks like you are passing an array, but I think transfer function transfers only one byte because `.len = 1;`.

```
struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
  .tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx,
  .rx_buf = 0,
  .len = 1, // <- HERE
  .delay_usecs = delay,
  .speed_hz = speed,
  .bits_per_word = bits,
  .cs_change=cs,
};
```

You want to transfer 3 bytes. You can modify the function and specify the length depending on the size of your array. Or, you can loop through your array and send one byte after another if you keep CS low between the transfers.

Comment: I tried your solution but it is still not writing to the LCD. I edited the below part uint16_t hl[] = {0x38,0x0E,0x06,0xF8,0x30,0x50,0x01,0x02};
        transfer(fd,hl, 0); // calling the transfer function
where 0xF8 is the first byte, 0x30 is the Lower byte and 0x50 is the upper byte. I am trying to write 'S'.

Comment: Isn't the start byte supposed to be 0xFA (RS is 1)? What are the other bytes (0x38, 0x0E, 0x06, etc)? I am not familiar with this specific SPI driver. But, in your code, looks like you are setting the tx buffer length to 1. Look at spi_ioc_transfer struct in your transfer function. Doesn't it mean you are telling the driver to transfer only one byte?

Comment: Thank you so much Sir your solution worked. I am able to write to the LCD.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured that out! By the way, if you often work on digital communication protocols (SPI, I2C, Serial, etc), you may want to get a logic analyzer. It is a great tool for debugging.

Comment: Hello sir, I am trying to write down the functions for the LCD initialisation with the same LCD screen using SPI. I am facing some problems as I am trying to execute the functions initially the screen gets stuck, then if I comment the above functions and see what happens the cursor still blinks. I am trying to do this from page number 29,30 and 33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40 of the data sheet. Could you please help me. I have not written all the 16 functions. But written a few of the starting ones.

Comment: Now as soon as I execute the last two functions from the above code the screen goes blank. Can you please tell me where am I going wrong in this? Also can you please tell me about the CGRAM,SEGRAM, DDRAM and the busy flag. I have edited the above code for the reference of the work that I have done. Regarding the suggestion of the logic analyser I would like to tell I am new to this platform once I will get used to it I will surely get one.

Comment: I’m willing to help. But you better not modify an existing question to ask a new one. My answer to your original question now doesn’t make sense and is no longer helpful to the community. Can you rollback the question and post a new question?

Comment: yes sir I will edit it again and make sure that the code looks as it was earlier. I will also post a new question. Thank You.

Comment: I have made the edits and made the question as it was earlier as well the code. Also posted a fresh question. I request you to please go through it. the title says:Initialising LCD eadip203-6 using functions overBeagleBone Black SPI. Sorry for the inconvinience.